# Add connectors WSO2 Enterprise Integrator

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

I have installed Enterprise Integrator 7.1 on Linux VM. Now I want add all available connectors to Enterprise Integrator /Micro Integrator. Because when  access the Micro integrator Dashboard (https://my.domain.com:9743/dashboard/connector) and select Connectors it says no record found. Can anyone help how I can add connectors to it directly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pack the connectors in a Connector Exporter Project in Integration Studio and export it as a CApp and then use it in Micro Integrator.

Have a look at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O2rAFdL8lZQ

Comment: Thanks for you answer , i have checked that link but that is for developer while creating project to add connectors according to their. i have task as system admin to deploy WSO2 EI with pre integrated connectors already in it. is it possible?

Comment: System admin can pack all the connectors into a separate connector exporter project and deploy it in the Micro integrator when running it for the first time. Deploying artifacts with CApps is the recommended approach in Micro Integrator

Comment: Ok got it . Thank you brother for your guidance . also their is any way i can integrate/use  wso2 API manager with  Enterprise Integrator/micro Integrator . i want to use both products for with each other?

Comment: You can front the Enterprise Integrator with an API manager. Services can be hosted in EI. The services will be exposed via APIM. ie you will give EI urls as backend URL when creating APIs in APIM.

Comment: OK THANK YOU SO MUCH. it helps a a lot